# Bash script is printing the wrong value

Tags: linux, bash, echo, quotes

I've created a script that seperates the IP that it finds, based on NIC card name input.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo what is your NIC?
read NIC
IP=`ifconfig $NIC 2>/dev/null|awk '/inet addr:/ {print $2}'|sed 's/addr://'`
NEWSTRING=${IP:0:6}
ALPHARETTA="12.101"
EUFAULA="12.102"

if [ "${NEWSTRING}" = "${ALPHARETTA}" ] ; then
  echo I'm in Alpharetta
else
  echo I'm in Eufaula
fi
```

If eth0 were to be 12.101.1.1 it would only take (12.101)

I'm comparing 12.101 and 12.101 for my tests... and i'm getting this echo back....

```
what is your NIC?
eth0
Im in Alpharetta
else
  echo Im in Eufaula
```

I'm obviously doing something silly, and not seeing it.. could somebody point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Run your code though http://shellcheck.net and come back when you fixed the mentioned errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bash parser is seeing the apostrophe characters you are trying to echo in the word "I'm" and it thinks you are trying to print one long string that spans from line 10 to line 12 of your script.  You can even see how the syntax highlighting on this site is also indicating a problem.  You should wrap the message you are echoing in quotes.  For example:

```
echo "I'm in Alpharetta"
```

Comment: Holy crap, cannot believe I forgot the damn "" lol. Thanks! :) I will accept as answer, but It wont let me do it for another 7 minutes.